# Nightwatch: .click() on select element isn't working

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I realize people have asked this question before but none of the solutions seem to have worked for me.

I'm currently trying to click on my `select` dropdown menu and select a value from the options available. However, calling `.click()` isn't doing the trick for me.

Here is what I'm attempting:

my pageObject:

```
sections: {
    addNew: {
      selector: "#my_form",
      elements: {
        name: "#name",
        mySelectDropdown: "#selectId"
      }
    }
  }
```

my code:

```
let addNew = page.section.addNew;
addNew.setValue("@name", 'test'); // this works as expected
addNew.click("@mySelectDropdown");
```

html:

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectId">
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
</select>
```

I would appreciate any insight, Thanks!

Comment: Well, it doesn't look like raw `Javascript`, right? What else is used here?

Comment: @CastroRoy I'm utilizing `Nightwatch` here. Unfortunately I didn't haven't enough reputation to add it as a tag but included it in the title

Comment: @iamdanchiv it tells me the element is not interactable- i've updated my code to include the HTML as well

Comment: @Tim Just a wild guess; if you're sure that the locator is absolutely correct; trying giving a pause before the click and see if it works? `browser.pause(2000)`

Comment: @AlapanDas Thanks that did the trick! Seems like I was attempting to click on the dropdown before it actually was ready to be clicked on

Comment: @Tim Glad it worked :)